# is there any framework to create graphs via terminal?

Tags: terminal

Removing the text since the question is closed as off topic. Have fun

Comment: Once again, I see on this site such things as off-topic, when the question is totally legit. I asked for anything that would produce a graph, usable via terminal. It does not seek product, services or learning material. If you consider this off-topic, then we can consider off topic 80% of the questions here on the site, and we end up with X people talking to each other about their personal issues at the workplace.

Comment: Ok, got it; this site is ran by few elected that dictate what stays and what goes...do you get money when you hit a certain number of answers? Good for you. Not wasting time here for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/).  It's probably best to install it using MacPorts or homebrew.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look at it.

Does this gnuplot accept a text file and make a graph using the data in it? I've found something that makes graphs but it accept only equations (basically act like a scientific calculator).

Comment: Yes, this is what I have used it for.  There are a lot of tutorials on the net, but I can't recommend any one in particular.

Comment: /right you are; found a tutorial based on how to feed data to the tool

http://www.gnuplotting.org/plotting-data/